# Only the last iteration is executed when iterating through parametrized URLs with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, callback, casperjs

I have this piece of code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var startID = 21;
var endID = 13533;
while (startID <= endID) {
    scrapPages(startID);
    startID++;
}

function scrapPages(i) {
    var str = "Starting to get the HTML for the problem" + i;
    console.log(str);

    var url = 'http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=' + i;
    casper.start(url, function() {
        this.echo(startID);
        var result = this.getHTML('td.problemText');
        casper.then(function() {
            var fileName = 'problem' + i + ".html";
            require('fs').write(fileName, result, 'w');
            this.echo("writing it to filename:  " + fileName)
        });
    });
}

casper.run();
```

All I'm doing is trying to parse Topcoder for all it's problems. I believe this question is not a duplicate of questions on Javascript Closures.

The problem is, the function `scrapPages` is running only once, the last iteration of `while` loop.

Can someone help me out why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many `start`s, but only one `run`. Both should be used exactly once. You can call `start` at the beginning before the loop without an argument and then change `casper.start` inside of `scrapPages` to `casper.thenOpen`.

You can verify that by going into the [code](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/1.1-beta3/modules/casper.js#L1691). When `start` is called all previously scheduled steps are lost.

Comment: Works. Thanks Artjom. Also can you please explain me why this is the case pls?

Comment: Looks like `casperjs` is your passion :)